# How to use secondary IPs as source for a ping request without assigning it on an interface

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ping

**Summary**
I have an Ubuntu VM that has a public IP address e.g. 1.1.1.1 assigned to its eth0 interface. upstream router has also routed another public IP subnet  e.g 2.2.2.0/256 to server's main IP address. Meaning if I assign an IP from that range e.g 2.2.2.1 from that subnet on a virtual interface eth0.1, I'm able to use that IP address in my ping tests like below:
ping -S 2.2.2.1 8.8.8.8

**Question**
How can I ping with the same source IP 2.2.2.1 without assigning it on a virtual interface?  The ideal would be to not needing to set IPs from this subnet anywhere inside the OS.

**What I've tried**
I've already tried setting the source IP without actually assigning it but with no luck

Comment: Check this: https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/ip.7#IP_TRANSPARENT . It would require both support from the application and proper routing in place.